# Django Cripsy Form - "This field is required" - shows on load

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

When the page loads I am seeing the error of - "This field is required" with the input form 'Title' highlighted with the red board. I would expect that this should only show after the Save button is pressed. I can toggle the message on and off with self.helper.form_tag but the behavior seems incorrect to me, it seems as though it is trying to submit before I click save.

Am I doing something wrong or is this expected behavior? If it is expected is there a way to change it to only show the warnings after Save?

[image]

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Request, RequestDocument
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Field, Div, Layout

class RequestForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'title'}))
    rfp_No = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={}), required=False)
    company_Name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={}), required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        #self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.help_text_inline = True
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(Field('title'), css_class='col-md-12', ),
            Div(
                Div(Field('rfp_No'), css_class='col-md-6', ),
                Div(Field('company_Name'), css_class='col-md-6', ),
                css_class='row',
            ),

        )
```

create.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form %}
    <button type="submit" class=" d-block btn btn-lg btn-success mt-4 w-50 mx-auto">
        Save
    </button>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".active").removeClass("active");
   $("#link-create").addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

adding self.helper.form_show_errors = False to the **init** hides the errors but this the block actual errors from showing such as if the max length was exceeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured this out by splitting the POST and GET methods in my form.

forms.py

```
form = RequestForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
       ##Do Post Stuff
    elif request.method == 'GET':
       ##Do Get Stuff
    else:
        context = {   
        }
    return render(request, "requests/create.html", context)
```